# Go program in certain directory get killed instantly on my macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, go, macos-big-sur

I have go program in my project that shows very strange behavior. It runs Ok from any folder, but not from the one ("unpack") it is unpacked by my other code. I have made "cp -R" of this directory to "unpack2" and renamed "unpack" to "unpack1" for clarity. Here how it looks like:

```
$ ls -lR
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 michael  staff  96 23 сен 09:36 unpack1
drwxr-xr-x  3 michael  staff  96 23 сен 09:36 unpack2

./unpack1:
total 206760
-rwxr-xr-x  1 michael  staff  105859154 23 сен 09:23 install

./unpack2:
total 229504
-rwxr-xr-x  1 michael  staff  105859154 23 сен 00:28 install
$ unpack1/install
$ unpack2/install
[1]    34435 killed     unpack2/install
$
```

"unpack1/install" runs with no problems
"unpack1/install" crashes

I have double checked that both "install" are the same binary

P.S.
I use macbook M1

Comment: How did you check they are the same binary? Did you verify they hash (md5, sha1 etc) to the same value? Also, the total length of the 3nd folder is bigger. Looks like there exists some extra files you have elided from the output.

Comment: I have used cmp command to compare files. Directories are same (ls -lasR) show same content. I see that "total" number is different, but I can not figure out what is this difference. "unpack" folder (before renaming to "unpack2" was created in go code (os.Makedirs()) and "unpack1" was created by "cp -R"

Comment: Folder is created using following call: os.MkdirAll(path, 0755)

Comment: Thanks. I think it's hard to say anything useful based on the available information. I suppose the source code of the binaries is not available (the only fact which is known is that they are written in Go), right? If so, I could think of the two ways to explore: 1) use `gdb` or `lldb` to run the binary and ask it to print the stacktrace after the binary crashes; 2) use `truss` or DTruss or whatever to try to trace the system calls made by the binaries and try to make out of the both logs the difference in behaviour.

Comment: I have source code - it is my project. Are there some useful debug approaches in this case?

Comment: I have managed to run tracing, but had to reboot machine to enable this. After reboot, this problem has gone. :/

Comment: I actually wonder why the message `killed` is not followed by the number of the signal which was actually sent to the process. By the way, is this a `bash` shell?